# Find the number of steps a string can be reduced to 0

Tags: c++, stl, time-complexity, c++14, complexity-theory

My assignment:

> You are given a non-negative integer variable $Z$. There are two actions available that can change its value:
>
> - if $Z$ is odd, subtract 1 from it;
> - if $Z$ is even, divide it by 2.
>
> These actions are performed until the value of $Z$ becomes 0.
>
> You have to write a function: `int solution(string &S);`
>   such that when given a string `S` consisting of $N$ characters containing a binary representation of the initial value of variable $Z$, returns the number of steps
>   after which the value of $Z$ will become 0, as described above.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

int solution(string &S) {
    int x = stoi(S, 0, 2);
    int count = 0;
    while (x != 0) {
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            x /= 2;
            count++;
        } else {
            x -= 1;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Now the time complexity of this code blows up. Where am I going wrong in writing an efficient solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now the time complexity of this code blows up. Where am I going wrong in writing an efficient solution?

You shouldn't convert the string into a number since it can too long to fit in a `32-bit` or even `64-bit` integer. Instead, what you should realise is that all we have to know is the number of `1`s `onesCount` and the length `size` of the integer string (we assume there're no leading zeros as per problem statement). Let's consider an example. Let's say we have a number `11001`. Then, the steps can be illustrated as below:

```
1 1 0 0 1   subtract rightmost bit because it's 1  
    |
    v         
1 1 0 0 0   right shift because rightmost 0  
    |
    V
0 1 1 0 0   right shift because rightmost 0 
    |
    v
0 0 1 1 0   right shift because rightmost 0 
    |
    v
0 0 0 1 1   subtract rightmost bit 1
    |
    v
0 0 0 1 0   right shift because rightmost 0 
    |
    V  
0 0 0 0 1   subtract rightmost bit 1
    |
    V
0 0 0 0 0   Complete.
```

So, as you can see, if the rightmost digit is `0` (and there are still `1`s to the left) then it takes one step to move to the next right digit. However, if the rightmost digit is `1` (and it's not the last one), then we need `2` steps - to nullify it and move to the next right digit. Obviously, if the leftmost digit is `1` and it's the last then it's only one step.

But then, the number of steps can be expressed as:

1. If a number is `0` then the number of steps is also `0`.
2. If there's only one occurrence of `1` then the number of steps is `size` of the string.
3. If there're more occurrences of `1`s then the total steps are `onesCount * 2 + (size - onesCount - 1)`. But then, this is more generic than section 2 and we can use it for both cases.

**Code**

```
uint32_t solveMe(std::string &number) {
    uint32_t onesCount = std::count(number.begin(), number.end(), '1');
    if (onesCount == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    uint32_t numberSize = number.size();

    return onesCount * 2 + (numberSize - onesCount - 1);
}
```

**Update**

As pointed out by @lucieon, another way of looking at this can be described by a formula below:

```
zerosCount + (onesCount-1)*2 + 1
```

Comment: Another way of looking at it is  `zerosCount + 2(onesCount) - 1` for everyone counted we multiply the value by 2 and subtract 1 from the value because the last 1 at the beginning of every binary, all the zeros before the first one value is insignificant

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution in C#, it covers the possibilities of having leading zeros.
cases such as '00011101' are covered.

```
public class Solution
{
    public static int EfficientCountStepsToZero(string S)
    {
        var newString = RemoveLeadingZeros(S);
        int zerosCount = 0;
        int onesCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < newString.Length; i++)
        {
            if (newString[i] == '0')
            {
                zerosCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                onesCount++;
            }
        }
        return zerosCount + (onesCount - 1) * 2 + 1;
    }

    private static string RemoveLeadingZeros(string S)
    {
        char[] letter = S.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < letter.Length; i++)
        {
            if (letter[i] == '1')
            {
                break;
            }
            letter[i] = ' ';
        }
        return new string(letter).Trim();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

// you can also use imports, for example:
// import java.util.*;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");

class Solution {

```
private static String RemoveLeadingZero(String xx)
{
    char[] letter = xx.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++)
    {
        if (letter[i] == '1')
        {
            break;
        }
        letter[i] = ' ';
    }
    String ans = new String(letter);
    
    return ans.trim();
}


public int solution(String S) {
    // write your code in Java SE 11

    String xy = RemoveLeadingZero(S);
    int zeroCount = 0;
    int oneCount = 0;
    int f= xy.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < f; i++)
    {
        if (xy.charAt(i)  == '0')
        {
            zeroCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            oneCount++;
        }
    }
    return zeroCount + (oneCount - 1) * 2 + 1;

    
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution in Kotlin, hope it helps:

```
private fun RemoveLeadingZero(xx: String): String {
            val letter = xx.toCharArray()
            for (i in letter.indices) {
                if (letter[i] == '1') {
                    break
                }
                letter[i] = ' '
            }
            val ans = String(letter)
            return ans.trim { it <= ' ' }
        }

fun solution(S: String): Int {
        val xy = RemoveLeadingZero(S)
        var zeroCount = 0
        var oneCount = 0
        val f = xy.length
        for (i in 0 until f) {
            if (xy[i] == '0') {
                zeroCount++
            } else {
                oneCount++
            }
        }
        return zeroCount + (oneCount - 1) * 2 + 1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here, is my solution for the dart, which I tested on the dartpad, it is working as expected.

```
void main() {
  String longStr = List<String>.generate(400000, (_) => '1').join();
  print(solution(longStr)); // 799999
  
  print(solution('011100')); // 7
  print(solution('111')); // 5
  print(solution('1111010101111')); // 22
}

int solution(String value) {
  String leadingZeroStr = removeLeadingZero(value);
  int zeroCount = 0;
  int oneCount = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < leadingZeroStr.length; i++) {
    if (leadingZeroStr[i] == '0') {
      zeroCount++;
    } else {
      oneCount++;
    }
  }
  return zeroCount + (oneCount - 1) * 2 + 1;
}

String removeLeadingZero(String value) {
  List<String> list = value.split('');
  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i] == '1') {
      break;
    }
    list[i] = ' ';
  }

  return list.join().trim();
}
```